# Pop up notification for user password expiry

Tags: powershell

All,

Thank for your feedback, I adapt some code that I got from you guys as this

```
$search = ([adsisearcher]"(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=User)(samaccountname=$ENV:USERNAME))").FindOne()

$user = $search.properties.name

$pwdlastset = [datetime]::FromFileTime($search.properties.pwdlastset[0]) 

$age = (New-TimeSpan –Start $pwdlastset –End (get-date)).Days

$expires =60-$age

if ($expires -lt 14){
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Windows.Forms'
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Your password will expire in $expires days.", "Your password will expire in $expires days!",[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK,[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Warning)
}
```

it works perfectly, for the users who password will expire in 14 days., anyway I want to check Domain Password Policy by

```
$MaxPasswordAge = (Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy).MaxPasswordAge.Days
```

but once it run by log on script on users profile is said this is not recognized even I force import-module ActiveDirectory.

anyway, it not perfect and still more room for improvement but at least it suits my work.

Thank a lot guys.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a script for this as the functionality is built into Windows Group Policy already, when set it displays a popup like this:

[image]

The policy you need to set is:

> Computer Configuration / Policies / Windows Settings / Security Settings / Local Policies / Security Options / **Interactive Logon: Prompt User to change password before expiration**

[image][image]

Comment: Thank you for your info, but my profiles people in my company they really ignore the balloon popup (trust me...I'm really fed up about their excuse) so that why I want to create the pop up for them while login to the system.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bit of an odd situation, where you want to run a user-side script, but i'm not aware of a way to get the password age or exact expiry date with just native .NET/PowerShell (i.e. no Get-AdUser)

```
$MaxPasswordDays = 30
$Searcher = [adsisearcher]::new()
$Searcher.Filter="SamAccountName=$($env:USERNAME)"
$User = $Searcher.FindOne().Properties
$PasswordSet = $User.pwdlastset
$Expires = [DateTime]::FromFileTime("$PasswordSet").AddDays($MaxPasswordDays*-1)
if ($Expires-(Get-Date) -lt 5){ #If Expires in 5 or less Days
    Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Windows.Forms'
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Your password will expire soon, press Ctrl+Alt+Del to change it")
}
```

if you hardcode the number of days a password is valid into the script you can use an `adsiSearcher` object to get the date their password was last set, then work backwards to display a messagebox, running this on startup via logon scripts is easy enough to do.

Regarding the actual issue and not the technical problem, I'd recommend using an email rather than a popup.

code I had lying around for an email reminder script : just swap out some of the stuff at the top until it works for you.

```
$RemindOn = @(1,3,5)
$FromAddr = "no-reply@domain.com"
$AdFilter = {Enabled -eq $True}
$Subject = "Password Expiry Reminder."
$PSEmailServer = "exchange-server-1.domain.local"

#region Message
#GivenName,Name,Expires,ExpiresIn,set custom vars above
$Message = '"** This is an auto-generated email, please do not reply **
Hi $GivenName,

We have detected your password is going to expire on $Expires ($ExpiresIn days from now)
Please change your password Immediately by pressing Ctrl+Alt+Delete and choosing ""Change a Password""

Regards,
IT"'
#endregion

#region Code Below
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Today = Get-Date

Get-ADUser -Filter $AdFilter -Properties "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed","EmailAddress","DisplayName","GivenName" | % {
    $ExpiresRaw = $_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed"
    if ($ExpiresRaw -ne ([Int64]::MaxValue)){ #never expires
        $ExpiresDate = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($ExpiresRaw)
        #Prepare vars for email body
        $GivenName = $_.GivenName
        $Name = $_.Name
        $Expires = $ExpiresDate.ToShortDateString()
        $ExpiresIn = [int]($ExpiresDate-(Get-Date)).TotalDays

        if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.EmailAddress) -and ($ExpiresIn -in $RemindOn)){
            #Send-MailMessage -From $FromAddr -To $_.EmailAddress -Subject $Subject -Body ($Message | iex)
        }
    }
}
#endregion
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir! I'll try to adapt to suite my need. I also recommend my Boss about Email notification, again this become an issued since they don't want to create more workload to exchange server. and don't want to disturb High profiles people in my company are very 1D10T problems.

Comment: @ApolloThai we've had this discussion previously, an email inconveniences them a lot less than an expired password was basically the point that got across, and if exchange will be brought down by 3-5% of your user base receiving one email sent from an internal source, you need to spec it differently - might as well get rid of group mailing lists y'know.